# Parse XML data to JSON (or array) - Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an api that fetches XML that looks like this:

[image]

As above picture shows, the XML contains several "item" each one contain the following properties:
title
link
description
pubdate
create
guid

How can I convert the above to JSON? Each item as an object with the same properties. Or an array for that matter so I can easily handle the data programatically. I use React.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [xml2json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json)

very simple to use, and can also convert back to XML if needed:

```
var parser = require('xml2json');
 
var xml = "<foo attr=\"value\">bar</foo>";
console.log("input -> %s", xml)
 
// xml to json
var json = parser.toJson(xml);
console.log("to json -> %s", json);
 
// json to xml
var xml = parser.toXml(json);
console.log("back to xml -> %s", xml)
```